# Bluetooth Disconnections

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetooth keyboard and mouse that have all of the sudden stopped connecting to my ubuntu box. They do still connect to another machine I have, so it seems as though something must have changed in the past 24 hrs or so that I can't seem to figure out.

Restarting bluetooth (sudo service bluetooth restart) allows the mouse and keyboard to connect for maybe 10 or 15 seconds, only to disconnect again.

Any recommended steps to troubleshoot bluetooth? I have tried changing AutoEnable to true in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf and have tried to change a USB blacklist in tlp following a post I found after a quick search, which didn't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: Also running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Did you run Ubuntu update today ?

Comment: I don't believe I did. Was able to resolve by reinstalling ubuntu on the machine, which isn't ideal, but it is what it is.